# Clone a CentOS VM on IBM x3650M2 server using Clonezilla

Tags: raid, clonezilla

First off very thanks to everyone for this portal.

What is am trying to do is to clone a CentOS virtual machine in VMware Workstation 10 to a physical hdd on an IBM System x3650 M2 (It's a 2U Rack Server) with a RAID Card on it. This physical hdd is the only one on this server and is configured in RAID 0.

**The problem:** I have cloned this VM to other physical hdd before using the exact method as described in this link [Link To Cloning Tutorial](http://daddy-linux.blogspot.in/2012/04/converting-vmware-image-to-physical.html). It always works if the physical hdd is to connect to a computer without RAID configuration. Now this IBM server i am trying with, does have a physical RAID card on it and i was forced to configure the only hdd on it as a RAID 0 configuration. So after the clone is successful and i connect the hdd back to the IBM server it never boots up into CentOS.

Can someone please flash some light on how to clone a VM to a physical hdd that is under a RAID 0 configuration. I think that the RAID configuration here is actually creating this problem.

Maybe i am wrong about RAID but i have no other idea left.

Comment: At this point, I'd consider a rebuild. Install a new OS and copy the data/configuration. Is that not an option?

Comment: This VM is an scratch install of ViciDial and takes lot of time to configure. Also i will have to install new servers very frequently so installing the same thing again and again is not going to be possible.

Comment: You may want to review RAID 0 part as choice of RAID type. If either drive fails your system and data is down/gone

Comment: The only option is RAID 0.